# C++: Having unicode console title..?

Tags: c++, unicode, console, title

When I try to set my console's title to a string that has unicode characters in it, using `SetConsoleTitle()`, the title displays just some garbage characters instead.
I have also tried the SetConsoleTitleW() function, but that gives me the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'const WCHAR*' for argument '1' to 'BOOL SetConsoleTitleW(const WCHAR*)'
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use wide string literal, that is:

```
SetConsoleTitleW(L"DиD");
```

The `L`, before a quote denotes, that this is a `wchar_t*` string.

Also, for completness I have to say, that in C++11, there are new string literal prefixes defined:

```
const char a[] = u8"for a UTF-8 string.";
const char_16_t b[] = u"for a UTF-16 string.";
const char_32_t c[] = U"for a UTF-32 string.";
```

as usual [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#New_string_literals) has more detailed note about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very good answer. (I'll accept this answer in 2 minutes, when the time limit goes away. )

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are attempting to send UTF-8-encoded data to a function that expects UTF-16-encoded data.

You need to either convert the string literal to UTF-16 (i.e. `WCHAR*`) before passing it to the function, or create the literal as a `WCHAR*` literal (which I believe is done using the syntax `L"DиD"`).